# Compose the correct FormData request

Tags: javascript, node.js, multer, form-data

By sending a request to the server through the postman everything works:

[image]

When trying to send the same request through the client, the `req.body` on the server is equal to an empty object:

```js
const img = ev.target.files[0];
const body = new FormData();
body.append('image', img);
body.append('user', localStorage.getItem('user'));
const data = await (await fetch(`${root}/api/upload/profile`, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
  },
  body
})).json();
```

`/profile` route:

```js
router.post('/profile',
    cors(corsOptions),
    async(req, res) => {
        upload(req, res, async err => {
            try {
                console.log(req.body) // {}
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err.stack)
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: By overwriting the `Content-Type` header, you are removing the boundary. Does it work if you remove that header?

Comment: @blex, really it helped me